# Syntax match using regex in c#

Tags: c#, winforms

```
while(condition)
{

}
```

i want to validate while loop any help?

```
string pattern = @"^(while("
```

am stuck here

Comment: As @Patrick Hofman Said, its not the best fit for the jop, but I added the regex to do this task only below.

Comment: In *general case*, you can't do this: `Regex` can provide *regular grammar* (with som minor extensions) validation only when you want *context free* grammar. Try using a *parser* (e.g. Antlr)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
string pattern = @"^while(.*?)\s*({.*?}|.*?;)"
```

Don't forget to set the `RegexOptions` to `SingleLine`

Comment: That is an invalid regular expression. (The `^(` fails)

Comment: Dont forget then to mark as an answer ;) @user3001880

Answer (score 6):

You can't validate such a complex structure (like most programming languages) using Regex. It is just not fit for the job.

If you want to go on with this, I would recommend to use a parser like ANTLR, and use one of the existing C# grammars to validate the `while` condition you have.

Comment: how to this with grammer?

Comment: Start by reading through the concept of ANTLR on their website. There are plenty examples out there. It would be too much to put that in an answer here since you have to understand quite a bit about ANTLR before everything makes sense.